# AngularJS and ASP.NET pass server session data to client

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am new in angularjs so it may be silly question.

I want to pass session data (username, securityid) to client(angularjs) and through controller(ang) display info on page. what i did on default page onready event update code like this

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
        
         var USER_NAME = '<%= USERNAME ?? "" %>';
         var USER_ID = '<%= USERID ?? "" %>';
....
});
```

and then trying to retrieve in my controller

```html
App.controller('HController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$iContentLoaded', function() {
        if (typeof USER_NAME === 'undefined' || typeof USER_ID === 'undefined') {
            $scope.USER_NAME ='XXX';
            $scope.USER_ID ='1234';
        } else {
            $scope.USER_NAME = USER_NAME;
            $scope.USER_ID = USER_ID;
        }
    });
}]);
```

somehow variable getting undefined, seem its my mistake as i am new to angularjs and not able scope it properly.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables:

```
var USER_NAME = '<%= USERNAME ?? "" %>';
var USER_ID = '<%= USERID ?? "" %>';
```

are defined inside a function, so they have function scope. Instead you want to make them global to be able to access them from your angular controller.